# Prevent flex items from overflowing container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to create a responsive first page website with multiple items.

This is what I want (the black square is the screen) :

[image: Normal screen]

[image: Reduced size]

[image: One line screen]

And this is what I have (it is a representation of what I would like to do):

```css
#main {
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Hey</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2">Item item item item item item item item</div>
    <div class="item3">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This is a paragraph1.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph2.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph3.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph4.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph5.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph6.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph7.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph8.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph9.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph10.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph11.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph12.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph13.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph14.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph15.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph16.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph17.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph18.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph19.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph20.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph21.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph22.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph23.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph24.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph25.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph26.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph27.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph28.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph29.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph30.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph31.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph32.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph33.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph34.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/540/

Comment: On wider screens, is the blue box supposed to be in the middle with the green box on the right, or all three boxes are aligned to the left with a margin between them?

Comment: @cjl750 In the normal screen, items position is correct, I just want to have a "margin" in bottom of my greenlist, and a scrollbar on it. For your question, it's : "all three boxes are aligned to the left with a margin between them"

Comment: Does this work, or were you trying to convert the floats to only use flex properties too? http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/541/

Comment: @cjl750 it's good, but, when it's not "one line page" I don't want a scrollbar on my main container (because it's an one page website). But I want to have a scrollbar on my greenscreen (because I can have 1000 items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that your third (green) item is set to `height: 100%`. This means it will take the full height of the container.

Except you also have a margin set.

```
.item3 {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 100px; 
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%; 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You also have an `h2` taking up height.

So, `height: 100%` + `margin-bottom: 20px` + `h2` is greater than 100% and causes an overflow.

Try this instead:

```
.item3 {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 100px; 
  max-width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px); 
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

That will solve the main problem.

Then, to get the scrollbar to work properly, adjust your `overflow` rules and add `display: flex` to `.item3`. This triggers full height on the child element which is enough to render a scrollbar.

```css
#main {
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* overflow: scroll; */
}

.item1 {
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

h2 { height: 20px; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h2>Hey</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2">Item item item item item item item item</div>
    <div class="item3">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This is a paragraph1.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph2.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph3.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph4.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph5.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph6.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph7.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph8.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph9.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph10.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph11.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph12.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph13.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph14.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph15.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph16.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph17.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph18.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph19.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph20.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph21.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph22.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph23.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph24.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph25.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph26.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph27.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph28.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph29.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph30.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph31.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph32.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph33.</p>
        <p>This is a paragraph34.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, to adjust the green item for smaller screens, consider media queries. Something like this:

```
@media ( max-width: 500px) {
  .item3 { height: 60vh; }
}
@media ( max-width: 300px) {
  .item3 { height: 50vh; }
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeAAb/543/)

Comment: I like your solution. I'm going to try it on my website.

Comment: it works good, but this what I have when I use '@media' to change my height (a big margin on my element) : http://i.imgur.com/ZQ0wTkE.png

Comment: See my jsfiddle demo. You may need to reset the `h2` margins.

Comment: Ok thanks, tomorow i'm going to fix little issues. Sounds good